# Adding a int variable to a Label and give it +1

Tags: c#, int, var, counting

I'm busy with an maze and i currently run on this problem. I want when ever someone hits the wall he uses the method `Movetostart` and i want to let it count with the var `death`. So far i got this.

```
int death = 0;
private void MoveToStart()
{
    Count.Text = death.ToString();
    Point startingPoint = panel1.Location;
    startingPoint.Offset(301, 543);
    Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(startingPoint);
    ms = 0;
    sec = 0;
    min = 0;
    hour = 0;
    death = +1;
}
```

The problem now is that death only stays on 1 and doesn't matter how many times it hits the wall it doesn't count up.

Comment: `death = +1` isn't quite the right syntax... think about what that statement means.

Comment: your logic is almost correct you need to assign the value of death back to the text box also read up on Operator overloads https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx

Comment: you could use death += 1, and you should put it in the Count.text after you change it not before

Comment: i also tried  `Count.Text = (Int32.Parse(Count.Text) + 1).ToString();` but that gives me an error for: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: @LeroyBeukers are you also using the debugger to step through the code.. until you get familiar with how to use the `+=` Operator you should stick to the old way of doing thing `death = death + 1;` you also need to understand the difference between `Casting (string) & Convet.ToString` methods.. do not over complicate your simple issue here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to increase `death` before you show it, or else it'll be shown off by 1:

```
private void MoveToStart()
{
   ++death;
   Count.Text = death.ToString();
   Point startingPoint = panel1.Location;
   startingPoint.Offset(301, 543);
   Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(startingPoint);
   ms = 0;
   sec = 0;
   min = 0;
   hour = 0;
}
```

using the `++` operator will increase the count by one and assign it back to the object, same as `death += 1;`.

The actual problem with your code is that `death = +1` is not the same as `death += 1`.  What you're doing is just re-assigning `death` to `+1`, or `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you wanted to write `death += 1;` and not `death = +1;`

Edit:
Also, like others have commented, you should assign the value to `Count.Text` after that you increment the value or your text on `Count.Text` will constantly be one step behind.

Comment: this is not an answer ..look at the code and you can clearly see that the OP is assigning a value to the TextBox initially but after incremented value of death it's not updating the textbox..

Comment: @MethodMan: Your right. I only gave half the solution. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add 1 to your "death" variable, you can write it like this

```
int death = 0;
private void MoveToStart()
{
    Count.Text = death.ToString();
    Point startingPoint = panel1.Location;
    startingPoint.Offset(301, 543);
    Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(startingPoint);
    ms = 0;
    sec = 0;
    min = 0;
    hour = 0;
    death++;
}
```

or

```
int death = 0;
private void MoveToStart()
{
    Count.Text = death.ToString();
    Point startingPoint = panel1.Location;
    startingPoint.Offset(301, 543);
    Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(startingPoint);
    ms = 0;
    sec = 0;
    min = 0;
    hour = 0;
    death = death + 1;
}
```

or create another variable which you are using to add to your death every time the method is called

```
int death = 0;
int _numberToAddEachTime = 1;
private void MoveToStart()
{
    Count.Text = death.ToString();
    Point startingPoint = panel1.Location;
    startingPoint.Offset(301, 543);
    Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(startingPoint);
    ms = 0;
    sec = 0;
    min = 0;
    hour = 0;
    death = death + _numberToAddEachTime;
}
```